# How can i make an interactive terminal with discord, more than just one command with an answer

Tags: discord.py, interactive

Im trying to create a fully featured terminal that i can use through discord a discord bot. Right now i can only type a command and get a response back, (like pip for example), Anything prompting me with a Y or N answer, or any extra input, is not sent back into discord. how would i do this?

Ive tried running asynchronous subprocesses using asyncio. expecting for me to be able to be able to answer Y/N questions. instead the same issue comes back and they do not render.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You'll find this helpful I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.